# Changing a value using case

Tags: mysql, database

I'm migrating a database and I need to change a column which is in integers to their associated category in string format. How can I check each value and change it on the fly using ifelse or switch/case/break?

```
SELECT *, Category FROM Members
  Category =
  Switch(category)
  if (value == 1 then change to "Category 1", value == 2 then change to "Category 2 and so on.)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, case when category = 1 then 'Category 1'
               when category = 2 then 'Category 2'
               else 'Category unknown'
          end as category
FROM Members
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL's CASE clause can do this.

```
UPDATE `Members`
    Set `Category` = CASE `Value`
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Category 1'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Category 2'
    END
WHERE `Value` IN ('1','2');
```

This means that any **and all** rows with `Value = '1'` will now also have `Category = 'Category 1'`. You can make this query more specific as necessary.